# when I want to see my admin penal in django it give me error not only admin in some urls it give me in some not this happen when I put to live db

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-settings

admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(models.User)
admin.site.register(models.Teacher)
admin.site.register(models.Student)
admin.site.register(models.CourseCategory)
admin.site.register(models.Course)
admin.site.register(models.Chapter)
admin.site.register(models.Section)
admin.site.register(models.StudentCourseEnrollment)
admin.site.register(models.CourseRating)
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {

'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'Django.DB.backends.MySQL,
    'NAME': 'LMSAPI',
    'USER':'admin',
    'PASSWORD':'12341234',
    'HOST':'mydb.cvijitliru7b.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT':'3306',
    'CHARSET': 'utf8',

 }
```

and this is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOT6C.png)

Error traceback:

```
    TypeError at /admin/login/
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 4.1.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
Exception Location: C:\Users\DIDAM\Desktop\venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py, line 371, in signature
Raised during:  Django.contrib.admin.sites.login
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DIDAM\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\DIDAM\\Desktop\\heroku_lms_api',
 'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\DIDAM\\Desktop\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\DIDAM\\Desktop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\DIDAM\\Desktop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\DIDAM\\Desktop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\DIDAM\\Desktop\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Tue, 01 Nov 2022 06:48:59 +0000
```

Comment: Can you share your template instead of sharing images?

Comment: which template can you help me

Comment: That you shown in image

Comment: Your question currently lacks a [mre], firstly post the **complete error traceback** (There's a button for a copy paste view on the debug page). Next from what I understand you get the error on the static template tag and from the limited information your error message shows it is related to the botocore package, please show your settings for configuring your static files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the ModelAdmin, [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

Comment: how should I add i do not know about it

Comment: I have this error in other places when I want to run API it give me same error

Comment: TypeError at /api/course-detail/1/
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/course-detail/1/

Answer (score 1):

stylesheet `block` should be outside the link tag of html.

In the template replace this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %} {% static "admin/css/base.css" %} {% endblock %}">
```

with this:

```html
{% block stylesheet %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'admin/css/base.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I did not get it where is stylesheet block

Comment: @PeshangayAram See that error image, that highlights the error part.

Comment: @PeshangayAram Also single quotes `'` are used inside double quotes `"`

Comment: but I do not have this in my code

Comment: @PeshangayAram You have, see in the link tag.

Comment: where is this ' and " quotes

Comment: @PeshangayAram Share your template in question by editing.

Comment: i could not see link

Comment: where should I find this line when I don't have this line of code

Comment: @PeshangayAram Share your `base.html` the link tag is there, see in error image.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I do not have base.html this file is not web app it is just backend and I connected to flutter at first I did not have this error but when I want to put it to rds and MySQL workbench and put it to server this error came

Comment: @PeshangayAram Then you should have explained in the question, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: @SunderamDubey that has nothing to do with the error, there's probably a misconfiguration in the settings for static files (with S3 buckets? the error points to botocore)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I don't know but think some another package of python, apologies hadn't seen the traceback clearly.

Comment: yes the error was because of the S3 buckets thank you so much for the help